# str_replace() doesn't work with array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an array like this:

```
array(46) 
{ 
[0]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> string(21) "Media/news/publishing" ["name"]=> string(20) "Cosmopolitan Armenia" ["id"]=> string(15) "146307748762264" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-03-20T14:40:43+0000" } 
[1]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> string(17) "Telecommunication" ["name"]=> string(5) "Zangi" ["id"]=> string(15) "386291674718829" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-03-20T11:07:46+0000" } 
[2]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> string(13) "Musician/band" ["name"]=> string(11) "Ray Charles" ["id"]=> string(12) "430894850091" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-03-16T22:03:46+0000" } [3]=> array(4) { ["category"]=> string(4) "Cars" ["name"]=> string(13) "I'm In Like With You" ["id"]=> string(15) "447042531989769" ["created_time"]=> string(24) "2013-03-16T22:01:46+0000" } .......
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this code:

```
str_replace("'","\'",MY_ARRAY);
```

... doesn't replace the `'` in  `"I'm In Like With You"`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to escape all array items recursively... your code can't work; [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) only replaces simply in string. You may use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to do this effectively:

In php 5.3 and higher (with support of [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)):

```
array_walk($data, function(&$item, $key){
    array_walk( $item, function(&$item, $key){
        $item = str_replace("'","\'", $item);
    });
});
```

Or use [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach( $data as &$v1){
    foreach( $v1 as &$v2){
        $v2 = str_replace("'","\'", $v2);
    }
}
```

But still, I'm having feeling you need this for escaping data for MySQL query and you should rather use function like [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-real-escape-string.php), [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), [`PDO::quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) or simply [placeholders in prepared statement](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Running_Statements_With_Parameters).

Comment: From the PHP documentation: "If subject is an array, then the search and replace is performed with every entry of subject, and the return value is an array as well."

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_replace`, you would need to loop through your array and do a `str_replace` on each of the values.

For example something like this:

```
foreach( $yourArray as $key => $value)
{
    $yourArray[ $key ]['name'] = str_replace("'", "\'", $value);
}
```

Read more about "Foreach" [`here`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace directly within an array. you can use arrays as the "find this" and "replace with" text, but what you're operating ON has to be a plain string.

You'll have to loop on the array and then do the replace operation on each string:

```
foreach($array as $key => $element) {
    $array[$key] = str_replace(..., ..., $element);
}
```

Given you've multiple separate strings in your array, you'll have to work on each one:

```
  $array[$key]['name'] = str_replace(....,...., $element);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple recursive function

Example

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->game = "GOW'4";
$object->whoami = "Peehaa'";

$array = array(
        "nice'kkk",
        "Fish" => array(
                "X" => "one'one",
                "obj" => $object
        )
);

print_r(str_replace_recursive("'", "*", $array));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => nice*kkk
    [Fish] => Array
        (
            [X] => one*one
            [obj] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [game] => GOW*4
                    [whoami] => Peehaa*
                )

        )

)
```

Function Used

```
function str_replace_recursive($search, $replace, $subject) {
    $result = null;
    if (is_array($subject)) {
        $result = array();
        foreach ( $subject as $k => $var ) {
            $result[$k] = str_replace_recursive($search, $replace, $var);
        }
    } elseif (is_object($subject)) {
        $result = clone $subject;
        foreach ( $subject as $k => $var ) {
            $result->{$k} = str_replace_recursive($search, $replace, $var);
        }
    } else {
        $result = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop inside your `array` and then use `$data` however you need

```
$array = array(array('category' => 'Media/news/publishing', 
           'name' => 'Cosmopolitan Armenia' ,
           'id' => '146307748762264',
           'created_time' => '2013-03-20T14:40:43+0000'),
 array( 
           'category' => 'Telecommunication',
           'name' => 'Zangi',
           'id' => '386291674718829',
           'created_time' => '2013-03-20T11:07:46+0000'), 
 array(  
           'category' => 'Musician/band',
           'name' => 'Ray Charles',
           'id' => '430894850091',
           'created_time' => '2013-03-16T22:03:46+0000'),
 array( 
           'category' => 'Cars' ,
           'name' => 'I'm In Like With You',
           'id' => '447042531989769',
           'created_time' => '2013-03-16T22:01:46+0000')
);

foreach($array as $arr)
{
    $data = str_replace('\'', '\\\'', $arr);
    echo $data['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

**this will output**

```
Cosmopolitan Armenia
Zangi
Ray Charles
I\'m In Like With You
```

you can change `str_replace` function as your needs you have just to change second parameter